# Google Semantic results question

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mark+zuckerberg+crunchbase

Guys, check out that search, in particular the first result's url. Crunchbase.com > People, and thus the people links to the /people section of the site.

How are they achieving it? I know Google algorithm is intelligent and looks for links and then makes the assumptions itself in cases, but is there any particular markup they are using to help Google to make these connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is light with details, but here's what they said in their [announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-site-hierarchies-display-in-search.html).

> The information in these new hierarchies come from analyzing destination web pages. For example, if you visit the ProductWiki Spidersapien page, you'll see a series of similar links at the top, "Home> Toys & Games> Robots." These are standard navigational tools used throughout the web called "breadcrumbs," which webmasters frequently show on their sites to help users navigate. By analyzing site breadcrumbs, we've been able to improve the search snippet for a small percentage of search results, and we hope to expand in the future.

Comment: Ah thanks for that :) I missed that announcement. I was wondering about it due to not seeing that! Thanks